# How to delete remain data in WP database after deleting custom post via admin interface

Tags: plugins, php, customization

I'm trying to create a plugin that will delete pictures and additional info from database on deleting custom post (sp_venue) via admin panel (wp-admin/edit-tags.php)

In the plugin I'm using this to catch the event:

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'kg_delete_post' );

function kg_delete_post($postId) {

    $post = get_post($postId);

    if ($post->post_type != 'attachment') {
        return false;
    }

    $url = str_replace($dirs['baseurl'],'',$post->guid);
    $urlParts = explode("/",$url);
    $numberOfParts = sizeof($urlParts) - 1;

    $dirs = wp_upload_dir();
    $fileNameParts = explode(".", $urlParts[$numberOfParts]);
    $fileName = str_replace('.' . end($fileNameParts), '', $urlParts[$numberOfParts]) . "-*." . end($fileNameParts);
    $path =$dirs['basedir'] ."/".  $urlParts[$numberOfParts-2] . "/" . $urlParts[$numberOfParts-1] . "/";
    $fullPath = $path  . $urlParts[$numberOfParts];
    $fullPathSearch = $path . $fileName;

    @unlink($fullPath);
    foreach (glob($fullPathSearch) as $filename) {
        @unlink($path . $filename);
    }
}
```

It works with:

```
wp_delete_post($Id, true)
```

But looks like the event on deleting via admin panel is no the same.

What should i use to make it works? Thank you.

Comment: Do **not** cross post around the network. Stick with [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486876/how-to-delete-remain-data-in-wp-database-after-deleting-custom-post-via-admin-in) please.

Comment: Also please fix your formatting.

Comment: @kaiser sorry, i didn't receive any answers on [my original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486876/how-to-delete-remain-data-in-wp-database-after-deleting-custom-post-via-admin-in) that's why i came here to more specific site.

Comment: As cross posting is [forbidden on StackExchange per the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), please decide which question you want to leave and which one you close or delete. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved, by adding my own js in admin panel to customize the click on delete button.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** and **how exactly** did that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post as the example seems to be doing exactly what you want to do in a situation. Your actual code as far as hooking into WordPress looks fine to me, but a key note to remember from the page I linked to is that this event is triggered by post deletion from the database, and not directly from clicking the button to trash a post in the admin panel.

So yeah, test with delete_post() and get back to me.

Comment: I've used this to write my example, but original code or changing the priorities changes nothing.